# CGRect and touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touch, cgrect

In this cocos2d app the nslog is not firing when I press the ccsprite. Could someone help me?

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2), 
                                   target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2), 
                                   27, 
                                   40);


CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(targetRect, touchLocation)) {            
    NSLog(@"Moo cheese!");
    }
}
return YES;   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the `targetRect` and `touchLocation` variables before the `if` ? Are they correct ? Is the method firing at all ?

Comment: did you enable touch with the property isTouchEnabled = YES; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layer init method add this

```
self.isTouchEnabled = true;
```

Use this code for touch detection

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    CGRect rect = [self getSpriteRect:yourSprite];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location))
    {
        NSLog(@"Sprite touched\n");
    }

}
```

To get sprite rect:

```
-(CGRect)getSpriteRect:(CCNode *)inSprite
{
    CGRect sprRect = CGRectMake(
                                inSprite.position.x - inSprite.contentSize.width*inSprite.anchorPoint.x,
                                inSprite.position.y - inSprite.contentSize.height*inSprite.anchorPoint.y,
                                inSprite.contentSize.width, 
                                inSprite.contentSize.height
                                ); 

    return sprRect;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the samething yesterday

Answer (score 3):

First of all be sure that you register the sprite for touches into the `onEnter` method for example:

```
- (void)onEnter
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:defaultTouchPriority_ swallowsTouches:YES];
    [super onEnter];
}
```

This will make your sprite touchable and so fire the event to the sprite when a user will press it.
Then refactor your code to make it more readable and test something like that:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    NSArray *targetsToDelete = [self touchedSpritesAtLocation:touchLocation];

    // Put your code here
    // ...

    return YES;
}

- (NSArray *)touchedSpritesAtLocation:(CGPoint)location
 {
    NSMutableArray *touchedSprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CCSprite *target in _targets)
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location))
            [touchedSprites addObject:target];

    return [touchedSprites autorelease];
}
```

It should return the targets that have been touched.